# CometD makes overkill of requests

Tags: tomcat, logging, tapestry, atmosphere, cometd

I keep seeing strange message in the log files of my webapp.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2013:23:00:53 +0000] "POST /cometd/connect HTTP/1.1" 200 147
```

This message is keep appearing in there and for the last few days I have seen in more then 20000 times in one hour so it managed to put my CPU to 100 utilization. Does anyone have idea what this is about?

If I try to go to that address it throw a 400 Unknown Bayeux Transport Exception

Comment: Too little information. Is this Atmosphere or CometD ? What exact versions, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a [CometD bayeux server](http://cometd.org/) deployed at your Tomcat and any client is accessing it using long-polling or callback-polling (the reason to have thousands of POST requests at your access.log).

This is normal and shouldn't make your CPU to be eaten unless you have an error in the application tied to your CometD.